# Snappy: How can I snappy compress a file?

Tags: java, snappy

I received a file, I need to compress this file and pass the file name of compressed file as an argument to another method.

```
File fileName = new File("fileA");
```

How can I snappy compress this file and get the file name of the compressed file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: [Snappy for java](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java)

First read the file to a String, then compress it:

```
String input = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("fileA"));

byte[] compressed = Snappy.compress(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String result = new String(uncompressed, "UTF-8");
```

Finally write it to a file of your choice:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("targetFile"),result,"UTF-8")
```

I have used [Apache Common FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for brevity here.